# Changing color of input box inside an Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array that includes 6 inputs from my Html.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="1" style="font-size: 30px; color: white; text-align: center;" onkeyup = "jump001(this, 'square2')" id ="square1" >
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" style="font-size: 30px; color: white; text-align: center;" onkeyup = "jump001(this, 'square3')" id ="square2" >
    <input type="text.css" maxlength="1" style="font-size: 30px; color: white; text-align: center;" onkeyup = "jump001(this, 'square4')" id ="square3" >
    <input type="text.css" maxlength="1" style="font-size: 30px; color: white; text-align: center;" onkeyup = "jump001(this, 'square5')" id ="square4" >
    <input type="text.css" maxlength="1" style="font-size: 30px; color: white; text-align: center;" onkeyup = "jump001(this, 'square6')" id ="square5" >
    <input type="text.css" maxlength="1" style="font-size: 30px; color: white; text-align: center;" id ="square6" >
```

the array in JS looks like this

```
var rowIndex1 = [square1, square2, square3, square4, square5, square6]
```

I've already defined each square as square1 = document.getElementById("square1").value           my only issue is that when I want to change the color of the input, I try to do something like this:

```
rowIndex1[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

I have it set up like this because I want to loop it and get it to go through each input and change the color accordingly, but if I don't call a specific square then the color doesn't change. Is there any way to change the color using the code I used above?

Comment: Have you added that array of inputs to the DOM? Trying to set the background colour of an element that doesn't exist in the page won't work.

Comment: I don't think I have, do you know how I would do that by any chance?

Comment: `square1 = document.getElementById("square1").value` You are storing the value into the variable, not  the element reference. You are trying to set a string's style!

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('#'+rowIndex1[i]).style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

Concat string like #square1,#square2,#square3,...

`Edit`

In array you are store like

```
square1 = document.getElementById("square1").value;
```

Change to this

```
square1 = document.getElementById("square1");
```

You just store element in arr

After you can use any where

Just like

```
rowIndex1[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

Comment: My loop already goes through each input, however my only issue is that JS doesn't recognize rowIndex1[i] as something that you can change the color of, even though it works when identifying the value. I cant change the color unless I define something specific like      document.getElementById("square1").style.backgroundColor = 'green'

Comment: @jeffjifferjay i edit answer check out and try this

Answer (score 0):

you can try it this way:

```js
let rowIndex1 = ['square1', 'square2', 'square3', 'square4', 'square5', 'square6'];
rowIndex1.forEach(el => document.getElementById(el).style.backgroundColor = 'green')
```

```css
.b1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="b1" maxlength="1" id ="square1">
<input type="text" class="b1" maxlength="1" id ="square2">
<input type="text" class="b1" maxlength="1" id ="square3">
<input type="text" class="b1" maxlength="1" id ="square4">
<input type="text" class="b1" maxlength="1" id ="square5">
<input type="text" class="b1" maxlength="1" id ="square6">
```